# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined..... IN MY NODEJS Project

Tags: node.js

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined
    at User.addToCart (D:\Pradip_All\Nodejs- tutorials video (MONGODB)\models\user.js:20:46)
    at D:\Pradip_All\Nodejs- tutorials video (MONGODB)\controllers\shop.js:70:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11212) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

[ERROR DESCRIPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR2ke.png)

Comment: Instead of images try posting your code so that's i easier to understand and answer

Comment: Can you add the code for `user.js` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `?` optional chaining operator that check if the value exists in the object.

```
const cartProductIndex = this.cart?.items?.findIndex((cp) => {
  return cp.productId.toString() === product._id.toString()
})
```

Comment: Thanks Miss,   Your code have some missing statements, but your code help me richOut Sollution.......